# Using --inspect-brk via NODE_OPTIONS

Tags: node.js

I am on Node.js versions 6+

I am trying to use the `NODE_OPTIONS` env variable which I believe is being backported back to Node.js version 6.

this is working for me:

```
node --inspect-brk foo.js
```

but this isn't

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect-brk" node foo.js
```

with the latter I keep getting "address already in use" errors, but the first always works.

any ideas?

Comment: At the moment, I am using Node version 9, and getting this problem, so it doesn't have to do with Node.js version 6.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that my node process is launching a child process - and this causes a problem when using NODE_OPTIONS. Because NODE_OPTIONS is an env variable, it will be used by the child processes too. And by default it uses a specific port `9229`, IIRC.

So the child process was using `localhost:9229`, just like its parent process and that causes the issue.

See this Github issue for reference:
https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/471